# How to remove lines from dataset

Tags: pandas, data-cleaning

I am trying to create a function (called "is_english") to identify any "non-English" character in the app's name from a data set and remove these apps from the data set. In my code, I'm considering any app that has more than 3 characters with an order higher than 127 as a non-english app. The 'App' expression means the column 'App' from the dataset.

```
def is_english(dataframe):


    for app in dataframe['App']:
        number_of_letter = 0

        for letter in app:

            if ord(letter) > 127:
                number_of_letter += 1

        if number_of_letter > 3:

            dataframe = dataframe.drop(dataframe[dataframe['App'] == app].index, inplace = True) 

            return dataframe

        return dataframe
```

[I don't know if it's possible to use the built-in function "ord()" in this case and if the code line **dataframe.drop(dataframe[dataframe['App'] == app].index** is correct. It seems that the function is not working and it goes directly to the last **return dataframe**. Can anyone help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLHrD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to know exactly what this problem looks like (post some example data), but my first suggestion is to simply build a list of the indices that you want to keep and then return a dataframe with those indices only.

```
def is_english(dataframe):
    for app in dataframe['App']:
        number_of_letter = 0
        l = []
        for letter in app:
            if ord(letter) > 127:
                number_of_letter += 1
        if number_of_letter > 3:
            l.append(dataframe[dataframe['App'] == app].index)
            keep = set(dataframe.index).difference(l)
            return dataframe.iloc[list(keep),:]
        return dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code directly returns is because of wrong indentation, the last `return dataframe` is indented once too much. There are some other ways how you could enhance your code:

- The function name `is_english()` implies that you would return a boolean, True or False. Something like `drop_non_english()` would be much more descriptive.
- No need for an enter between each line, which makes it unnecessarily long and harder to read.
- you can put the second if-statement also in the for loop so you can immediately delete the app after three non-English characters are found instead of looping over the entire word.
- DataFrames aren't "made" for looping over, as CopyOfA suggests, building a list with indices to keep and then using `return dataframe.iloc[indices]`
- Now your function will return after finding one non-English app, I suppose you would want to delete all apps so consider repositioning the return statement.